# What is the irradiance on a point due to a flat plate?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

The situation I am asking about is as follows: You have a flat, rectangular plate of material of length a and width b. This plate is radiating light (as a Lambertian emitter) at an intensity I. A small (compared to the radiating plate) sphere is positioned z meters "above" the plate's center. What is the irradiance that the sphere receives from the plate?

Additional, follow-up questions: What happens if it is a small, flat plate parallel to the radiating plate instead? And what if it is displaced from the center axis of the radiating plate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd have to integrate along the emitting surface. You better consider that the sphere is like a disc completely opposite the emitter, or your integration will become impossible. IF it is opposite to it, you have

$\int_{y=0}^b \ \int_{x=0}^a \ \  L_e\frac{cos^2 (\hat N,\hat r)}{r^2} dxdy  $

And, since there's not too much symmetry, this integral can be extremely hard, even impossible to solve it analytically, but don't worry, you can ALWAYS find the numerical value, and that's not a disgrace.

Comment: Ah, so there is no simple, clean method to do it even with simplifying assumptions? How would it be if the emitting plate were infinitely large, then? And also, this isn't for homework or anything - it is just something I was curious about, specifically to estimate what sorts of thermal environment you'd have around the radiators of a spaceship.

Comment: That's right, stating the problem is easy, but solving it is not. An emmiting plane infinitely large is easier, because that means emission is perpendicular to the plate.  If so, the calculation is much easier. In this kind of problems, like in electromagnetism, only simmetries can help you get the integral analytically.